# Puzzle: Finding the ratio of cevians inside triangle.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Given a triangle ABC, with cevians AD, BE and CF whom intersect in P. Given are the ratios |BP|/|PE| (in the case of my puzzle this is 3/2) and |FP|/|PC| (here it is 3/4). Find the ratio |AP|/|PD|.

Now I've tried looking at ceva's and obel's theorems, but I can't find the link between the ratios of |AD|/|AB| and the ratios of the cevians. (idk if this is the path to victory)

Comment: Where is the point $P$?

Comment: I wrote S instead of P. Edited now!

Answer (score 0):

suppose $\frac{BP}{PE}=b$, and $\frac{FP}{PC}=c$.

$\frac{PE}{BE}=\frac{S(ABC)}{S(APC)}$, where $S(XYZ)$ is area of triangle $XYZ$, so
$$\frac{PE}{BE}+\frac{PF}{CF}+\frac{PD}{AD}=\frac{S(ABP)+S(ACP)+S(BCP)}{S(ABC)}=1.$$
$$\frac{PE}{BE}=\frac{PE}{PE+PB}=\frac1{1+\frac{PB}{PE}}=\frac{1}{1+b}$$
and $$\frac{PF}{CF}=\frac{PF}{PF+PC}=\frac{\frac{PF}{PC}}{\frac{PF}{PC}+1}=\frac{c}{c+1}$$.
which means $\frac{PD}{AD}=1-\frac{1}{1+b}-\frac{c}{1+c}$, and $$\frac{AP}{PD}=\frac{AD}{PD}-1=\frac{1}{\frac{b}{1+b}-\frac{c}{1+c}}-1=\frac{(b+1)(c+1)}{b-c}-1=\frac{bc+2c+1}{b-c}$$

Comment: Why is PE/BE equal to the ratio of those two areas? @snowAuoue

Comment: @user245683 $S(ABC)=BE\cdot AC \cdot \sin(\angle BEC)$ and $S(APC)=PE\cdot AC\cdot \sin(\angle BEC)$

Answer (score 0):

Two terms from the following sum (in the L.H.S.)
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{PD}{AD} +
\frac{PE}{BE} +
\frac{PF}{CF}
&=
\frac
{\operatorname{Area}(PBC)}
{\operatorname{Area}(ABC)}
+
\frac
{\operatorname{Area}(PCA)}
{\operatorname{Area}(BCA)}
+
\frac
{\operatorname{Area}(PAB)}
{\operatorname{Area}(CAB)}
\\
&=
\frac
{\operatorname{Area}(ABC)}
{\operatorname{Area}(ABC)}
=1
\end{aligned}
$$
are implicitly given, and from the third one we immediately have the answer.

---

Later edit: Some more details.

- Note that for two triangles like $\Delta PBC$ and $\Delta ABC$ that share a common base, in this example $BC$, the proportion of their areas is the same as the proportion of the corresponding heights w.r.t. the common base. Drawing the heights, we see that the proportion of the heights is $PD:AD$. ($AD$ was corrected as denominator above, the denominators are full cevians, the numerators are the part of the cevians from $P$ to their side intersections $D,E,F$.)
- To see that two of the three fractions are *implicitly* given, let us start with the example
  $FP:PC=3:4$. Then
  $$
  \frac{FP}{FC}
  =
  \frac{FP}{FP+PC}
  =
  \frac{3}{3+4}\ .
  $$

Comment: 1. What do you mean with L.H.S.?

2. The terms you are given are unknown in my problem. (PF/CF etc.)

3. How do you equate those terms to the ratios of areas?

Comment: L.H.S. is a short cut for "left hand side", this is the expression we started with, the sum of three fractions of the shape part of the cevian (its length) divided by the full cevian (its length).